# Вопрос по циклам while в битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

Знаю что у обычного цикла while есть внутри условие остановки: `while ($i <= 10)`

Объясните пожалуйста как работает цикл из битрикса:

```
while($arPath = $rsPath->GetNext())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цикл с предусловием while работает по следующим принципам:

Вычисляется значение логического выражения.
Если значение истинно, выполняется тело цикла, в противном случае - переходим на следующий за циклом оператор.

```
while (логическое_выражение){
    тело цикла;
}
оператор;
```

При каждой итерация сначала выполняется логическое_выражение(`$arPath = $rsPath->GetNext()`), если оно истинное(`true`) то выполняется тело цикла. Поскольку в php выполнения происходит справа на лева, то есть сначала выполняется вызов функции `GetNext()`, объекта `$rsPath`, после чего значения которое она(`GetNext()`) вернет, присваивается переменной `$arPath`, которая и будет проверяться на истинность, то есть будет логическое_выражение.
    При каждом вызове `GetNext()` в переменною `$arPath` будет записан следующий элемент массива и  перемещает внутренний указатель  массиве результата выборки на следующий элемент, который будет возвращаться при следующим вызов метода `GetNext()`. Если достигнут конец массива результата выборки метод `GetNext()` вернет `false`, который будет присвоен переменной $arPath.В случае если логическое_выражение, в этом случае переменная  $arPath, не истинно(`false`) то тело цикла не выполнетса.

Answer (score 0):

`$rsPath->GetNext()` возвращает что-то, что присваивается `$arPath`, потом проверяется значение логическом контексте на условие продолжения цикла.

Answer (score -2):

Условие остановки – когда объект `$arPath` станет `false`.